# Android Emulator - Ubuntu 14.04 - Screen starting up Black

Tags: android, ubuntu

Hey I am using the Android SDK API level 21 (lollipop) on an Ubuntu 14.04 system.
I have installed QEMU and enabled hardware virtualization on my machine (KVM up running and registered), but whenever I try to start the AVD that I created using the SDK manager the instance never provides me with an android home screen, it just stays black.

CLI Command: emulator -avd heyholetsgo -debug-all -qemu -enable-kvm

Paste bin of logcat: http://pastebin.com/NYSZdvSP

Any help would be awesome!

Comment: why qemu/kvm when genymotion / virtualbox run very good on ubuntu? I would rm qemu/kvm and go geny...

Comment: Honestly, I did not know of genymotion and I will most definitely try it out thank you!

Comment: make sure to remove KVM or it will collide with geny dependency 'virtualbox'